# In R directly go to next iteration of for loop if the current one has an error

Tags: r

I am running a $for$ loop in $R$. There are about a million iteration. It so happens that some of the iterations lead to an error. The error may be different for different iterations. The question is: How to skip an iteration if there is an error in it without checking for a specific condition(which is usually done to exit a for loop)....i.e. here the condition to exit the current iteration is that the iteration has an error.
I just want to skip the erroneous iteration and o to the next iteration.

Something like:

```
if error:
  output = 0
  skip to next iteration
```

Comment: wrap your code in a `tryCatch` block. I have voted to migrate this question to stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `try` or `tryCatch`. For example, squaring the values in a simple list of integers and characters:

```r
vec <- list(1, 2, 3, "c", 4, 5, 6)
```

Use `try` to simply continue when an error is encountered:

```r
for (x in vec) {
    try(print(x^2), silent = T)
}

# [1] 1
# [1] 4
# [1] 9
# [1] 16
# [1] 25
# [1] 36
```

Use `tryCatch` to do something like print a specific message, etc.:

```r
for (x in vec) {
    tryCatch(print(x^2),
             error = function(cond) message(paste(x, "is not a number"))
             )
}

# [1] 1
# [1] 4
# [1] 9
# c is not a number
# [1] 16
# [1] 25
# [1] 36
```